# Notifications of sticky filters that have been applied

Tags: filter, notification, faceted-search

I am curious as to whether notification of sticky filters should be shown or not.

On the attached screenshot you will see a "Translate search terms" function. If you setup the translation, then you can perform a search that includes other languages, so a search for "black" would pull in "zwart", "noir", etc. depending on which languages you included in the setup process.

In the "Matches for" section I currently only show the actual search term "black", with a way to remove that one term. If I was to list the various possibilities of a term in all languages, then that section would become unwieldy.

Would you suggest:

1) Adding a note below the match to say "Search term translations applied" 
2) Adding a note below the match to say "Search terms translated into (languauge 1),(language 2) etc.
3) Don't worry - the filter is checked below.
4) Anything else???

[image: translation settings]

Comment: What are the target devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about relocating the "Translate search terms" check box to the top, right below "Matches for: black"? This way, these two would appear to be more connected. After all, the search terms are what the check box relates to.

Also, about terminology: you use both "search terms" and "keywords". If these both mean the same thing, then just pick either and go with it.